# how to show from certain date onwards

Tags: sql, database

I want to show dates from a certain date onwards but limit them to 7 rows 
eg: I want to show dates from 2018-01-11 and up to 7 rows

```
SELECT 
EmployeeID,[Date], ShiftType, Shift_Description
FROM
Roster r inner join ShiftType s on r.ShiftType = s.ShiftID 
WHERE EmployeeID = 123123
ORDER BY [Date] ASC;
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Always add the tag for your database. SQL answers can be different from one database to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your database, but it seems to be SQL Server from the screenshot and your query syntax, so I will answer based on that.

You can use the `TOP` statement to get the first 7 records after you add the date condition:

```
SELECT TOP 7
EmployeeID, [Date], ShiftType, Shift_Description
FROM Roster r
INNER JOIN ShiftType s ON r.ShiftType = s.ShiftID 
WHERE EmployeeID = 123123
  AND [DATE] >= '2018-01-11'
ORDER BY [Date] ASC;
```

Also you can use the `DATEDIFF()` function to compare the dates. In this query, it starts with at least a day after 2018-01-10:

```
SELECT TOP 7
EmployeeID, [Date], ShiftType, Shift_Description
FROM Roster r
INNER JOIN ShiftType s ON r.ShiftType = s.ShiftID 
WHERE EmployeeID = 123123
  AND DATEDIFF(DAY, '2018-01-10', [DATE]) > 0
ORDER BY [Date] ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a date conditional and a limit to your query:

```
SELECT 
EmployeeID,[Date], ShiftType, Shift_Description
FROM
Roster r inner join ShiftType s on r.ShiftType = s.ShiftID 
WHERE EmployeeID = 123123 AND Date > '2018-01-11'
ORDER BY [Date] ASC
LIMIT 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

For `MySQL` use `Limit`:

```
SELECT 
EmployeeID,[Date], ShiftType, Shift_Description
FROM
Roster r inner join ShiftType s on r.ShiftType = s.ShiftID 
WHERE EmployeeID = 123123 AND Date >= '2018-01-11'
ORDER BY [Date] ASC
LIMIT 7;
```

For `SQL Server` use `TOP`:

```
SELECT Top 7
EmployeeID,[Date], ShiftType, Shift_Description
FROM
Roster r inner join ShiftType s on r.ShiftType = s.ShiftID 
WHERE EmployeeID = 123123 AND Date >= '2018-01-11'
ORDER BY [Date] ASC;
```